# Excel vba, display value in a textbox that I fetch from a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that ranges from F2 to G230 . The F column is employee number and G column is employee name. Im trying to make a simple program that registers food orders for the employees and exports the data into a table. Everything works fine except when I choose a employee from a drop down list I want the employee number to appear in a textbox.

Here is my whole code:

```
Private Sub cmdbutton_add_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("listi yfir skráningar")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,          LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.combobox_name.Value) = "" Then
Me.combobox_name.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please complete the form"
Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.textbox_staffnr.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.combobox_name.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.combobox_rettir.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.textbox_verd.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.textbox_dags.Value

MsgBox "Komið :)", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Komið"
'clear the data
Me.combobox_name.Value = ""
Me.combobox_name.SetFocus
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Cmdbutton_close_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub combobox_name_Change()

textbox_staffnr.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.combobox_name.Value,     Sheet3.Range("F2:G230"), 1, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub combobox_rettir_Change()

textbox_verd.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.combobox_rettir.Value,     Sheet3.Range("C2:D23"), 2, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub Name_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub textbox_staffnr_Change()



End Sub

Private Sub textbox_verd_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
textbox_dags.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub

And here Im getting error:

Private Sub combobox_name_Change()

textbox_staffnr.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.combobox_name.Value,     Sheet3.Range("F2:G230"), 1, 0)

End Sub
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** From user's comment:

> The number is in column 1 and the name is in column 2

In that case, Vlookup won't work, you'll need to use Index/Match, or a Range.Find.Offset.  Personally I prefer the Range.Find.Offset while in VBA:

```
Dim rngFound as Range

Set rngFound = Sheet3.Range("G2:G230").Find(Me.combobox_name.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If not rngFound is Nothing Then textbox_staffnr.Value = rngFound.Offset(0, -1).Text
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that's not it. I already have this functional in the same userform but in this specific textbox, it is not working.

Comment: What's the name of the textbox that needs to be populated?

Comment: And what is the name of the combobox where you are selecting the employee number?

Comment: I choose employee name from combobox_name and I want the employee number to appear in textbox_staffnr.

Comment: If that's the case, the code I pointed is the issue.  You are looking up the name, and also returning the name (column 1) instead of the number (column 2).  That's why the 1 needs to be a 2.

Comment: The number is in column 1 and the name is in column 2, any ideas?